# Quickly assign an array to n bins with equal length

Tags: python, numpy, binning, discretization

For example, I have a stream of array with numbers ranging from `0.0` to `10.0` inclusive.

I want to assign the numbers in `arr` to `5` bins of equal length quickly.

By equal length I mean the bin intervals are `[0.0, 2.0), [2.0, 4.0), [4.0, 6.0), [6.0, 8.0), [8.0, 10.0]`.

The problem is that the last interval is not same as the other intervals.

Test:

```
import numpy as np
# Things we know and can pre-calculate
n_bins = 5
minimal = 0.0  
maximal = 10.0
reciprocal_bin_length = n_bins / (maximal - minimal)

# Let's say the stream gives 1001 numbers every time.
data = np.arange(1001)/100

norm_data = (data - minimal) * reciprocal_bin_length
norm_data = norm_data.astype(int)
print(norm_data.max())
print(norm_data.min())
```

Result:

```
5
0
```

The bin index should be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, but not 5.

Comment: I think you may be looking for [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html).

Comment: min is 0. max is exactly 10 that way. digitize allows bin of uneven length and might be slower. this is equal length.

Comment: what about [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

Comment: @jeremycg I tried to read the source code of pandas.cut. It  seems to adjust the max beforehand, like multiplying the max by 1.001. That gives some small error in binning, but don't need to clip afterwards.

Comment: Your logic is fine, you are just missing one line at the end: `norm_data[norm_data >= n_bins] = n_bins -1`, equivalent to the posted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "*poor man's solution*" could be to calculate the [*minimum*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) between your array `norm_data` and `nbins-1`:

```
norm_data = np.minimum(norm_data,nbins-1)
```

So all `5`s (and above) will be converted into `4`s. Mind that of course here you will not do a proper range check (`120.0` will also end up in bin 4).

Answer (score 0):

If 0.1% error is acceptable, the following is a bit faster.
Not sure if this is fine with floating point rounding.

```
import numpy as np
# Things we know and can pre-calculate
n_bins = 5
minimal = 0.0  
maximal = 10.0
approx = 1.001  # <-- this is new
reciprocal_bin_length = n_bins / (maximal*approx - minimal)

# Let's say the stream gives 1001 numbers every time.
data = np.arange(1001)/100

# can use numexpr for speed.
norm_data = (data - minimal) * reciprocal_bin_length
norm_data = norm_data.astype(int)
print(norm_data.max())
print(norm_data.min())
```

Comment: clipping to both 0 and n_bins - 1